# Construct basis of space of commuting matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we are given matrices $\mathcal{A}=\{A_1,\ldots,A_n\}$ which don't necessarily commute with one another, and we want to find a matrix $B$ that simultaneously commutes with all of them (assuming such a matrix exists other than multiples of the identity). How would one construct the basis for the set of matrices $\{B|BA=AB\forall A\in\mathcal{A}\}$?

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is in Jordan Normal Form then the centralizer $C(A) = \{X \in \mathbb M_n(k) \ | \ AX = XA\}$ of $A$ isn't too hard to figure out.  Then for invertible $B$ we have $C(BAB^{-1}) = BC(A)B^{-1}$ so this will let you figure out $C(A)$ for any matrix $A$.  Finally the set you're looking for is $C(A_1) \cap \cdots \cap C(A_n)$.

Of course this is a pain to do by hand.  But it's probably better than just letting $B$ be a generic matrix with variables as entries and solving the huge system of equations $A_iB - BA_i = 0$.